# Android Studio Unit test | Days.daysBetween fail randomly

Tags: kotlin, junit

I am failing to understand why the following test fails some times, while other times it works.
What I'm trying to get is the count of days left from a date. It seems to work some times but sometimes it doesn't. This is because instead of counting the days as suggested, it counts one less and I don't understand why it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't.

**Here the function:**

```
internal fun getRemainingDays(itemDate: Date): Int? {
    if (itemDate == null) return null
    return Days.daysBetween(LocalDate(Date()), LocalDate(itemDate)).days
}
```

**Here my test:**

```
@Test
fun getRemainingDays() { 
    val testDate = LocalDate(Date()).plusDays(2).toDate()
    assertThat(viewModel.getRemainingDays(testDate), equalTo(2))
}
```

Comment: Every time you do `Date` a new "current time" will be applied. If the time between `Date()` in your test code and `Date` in your `getRemainingDays` method is sufficiently large to be noticable, then the there will be *slightly less* than 2 days between `testDate` and `Date`

Comment: Wait: what exactly are `LocalDate` and `Date` in your example? `java.time.LocalDate` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. In my tests. The problem was in the result that the `LocalDate` function offers when I go to write:

```
val testDate = LocalDate(Date()).plusDays(2).toDate()
```

In fact, `testDate` will not be equal to today's date plus 2 days but will stop at midnight, thus giving as a result not the current date plus two days but the current date plus about a day and a half. For this reason the test fails.

To get exactly the current date plus two days (in my test case) I didn't have to use `LocalDate` but `LocaDateTime` which returns the correct value.

This test now pass correctly:

```
@Test
fun getRemainingDays() { 
    val testDate = LocalDateTime(Date()).plusDays(2).toDate()
    assertThat(viewModel.getRemainingDays(testDate), equalTo(2))
}
```